# Access hostname routed from hosts file on separate machine

Tags: iis, dns, hosts

I'm working on a project on my PC. I've set up IIS to run my code on a certain IP, let's say my application runs on `123.45.67.8`. I've then edited the `hosts` file on my machine, to point the IP to a certain hostname; `123.45.67.8` now points to `example.site.com`.

Now, I have to test some features of my application in another environment so I've set up a VM as a testing environment. Problem is, to test this I need to access my application through the hostname routed in my `hosts` folder on my machine, THROUGH my VM. I realize that my VM has no knowledge of the rerouting of my `hosts` file, and I'm stumped on how to solve this. Is there any way to access  the locally routed hostname from another machine, or do I have to actually host my application online?

Comment: You can make an entry in your VM's host file the same way you did for your local PC.

Answer (score 1):

As you are only testing, and using the local hosts file for temporary redirects; in this scenario I would also update the local hosts file on the VM to create the desired hosting route (to mimic what you have configured on your PC basically).

Comment: Does this work? As the application is not running on the VM - there is nothing on the desired IP, so if I try to route through the `hosts` file, it just says nothing is found. Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: Is the VM running on your local PC, and your local PC is also hosting the application?

If configured like the above, you should be able to share a virtual interface between the VM and your local machine, so they can talk to each other on a private subnet. It's this IP you would need to enter into your hosts file on the VM (after confirming you can ping or telnet successfully on the port required by your application, from the VM to your local PC).

How to set this up differs between what OS and VM service you have installed, such as Virtual Box, or VMWare etc.